# Using the images of the server (ListFragment Android)

Tags: android

Using the image of the server instead of native images
I want my server images and text on my list.
Thank you very much

```
        List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("txt", "Country : " + countries[i]);
        hm.put("cur", "Currency : " + currency[i]);
        hm.put("flag",Integer.toString(R.drawable.abc_ab_share_pack_holo_light) );
        aList.add(hm);
    }

    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.flag,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout1, from, to);

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the Image URL as string and then can retrieve the image to your View as you like.You can use some Image Loaders Like Picasso(http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load the image to your view!